# Sweeping algorithm in Java 8 streams

Tags: java, algorithm, java-stream

I have a program that, at its core, processes sorted lists (one medium-sized `database` and one large list of `queries`) of intervals, both lists are sorted. Each database interval should be matched to all overlapping queries and then the query list is to be written out in the same order as it was read in.

This is similar to the sweep line family of algorithms (correct me with a better wording here please, if possible).

To make the program run with really large inputs, I would like to (1) work as "local" as possible and (2) write out data as soon as possible (that is if a query is not required any more it should be written out).

The whole task is a bit clunky to implement, but a MWE looks somewhat as given on the bottom. Actually, the database is not that big and could be loaded into memory into an interval tree or so. However, the problem of processing the queries remains.

My question is now: Is there an elegant solution that uses Java 8 streams such that I can benefit from parallelism (processing a DB with multiple queries is somewhat expensive)?

I realize that one challenge is grouping each query record with more than one database record. Another challenge is local merging of results as soon as a query is completely processed and no future one can interfere with the next one to write out.

Thanks!

```
package mwe;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

class MWE {

    // Half-open interval [begin, end)
    public static class Interval {
        String name;
        int begin;
        int end;

        Interval(String name, int begin, int end) {
            this.name = name;
            this.begin = begin;
            this.end = end;
        }

        boolean overlaps(Interval that) {
            return (that.begin < this.end) && (this.begin < that.end);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Interval [name=" + name + ", begin=" + begin + ", end=" + end + "]";
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + begin;
            result = prime * result + end;
            result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Interval other = (Interval) obj;
            if (begin != other.begin)
                return false;
            if (end != other.end)
                return false;
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }

    // One counter for an interval
    static class IntervalCounter {
        int counter;
        Interval itv;

        IntervalCounter(Interval itv) {
            this.counter = 0;
            this.itv = itv;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "IntervalCounter [counter=" + counter + ", itv=" + itv + "]";
        }

    }

    // DB intervals to come, sorted by begin position
    static List<Interval> inactiveIntervals = new ArrayList<>();
    // Currently active DB intervals, sorted by begin position
    static List<Interval> activeIntervals = new ArrayList<>();
    // Mapping from database to query interval
    static HashMap<Interval, ArrayList<Interval>> dbToQueries = new HashMap<>();
    // Mapping from interval to point into list of outgoing intervals
    static HashMap<Interval, IntervalCounter> itvToCounter = new HashMap<>();
    // List of outgoing qry intervals
    static ArrayList<IntervalCounter> outgoingIntervals = new ArrayList<>();

    static void process(List<Interval> db, List<Interval> qry) {
        inactiveIntervals.addAll(db); // put all into queue

        // Process each query interval
        for (Interval q : qry) {
            assignToIntervals(q);
            processDone(q);
        }

        assignToIntervals(null);
        processDone(null);
    }

    /**
     * Given the current Interval q, process all database intervals for which no more overlap can come
     */
    private static void processDone(Interval q) {
        // Count number of database intervals that are done when q has been processed completely
        int popCount = 0; // number of intervals to pop from front
        for (Interval db : activeIntervals) {
            if (q == null || q.begin >= db.end) {
                System.err.println("Processing in DB " + db.name);
                for (Interval itv : dbToQueries.get(db))
                    System.err.println("  " + itv.name);
                popCount += 1;
            } else {
                break; // cannot guarantee done for next
            }
        }

        // Remove them from the DB list and reduce counters of contained queries
        while (popCount > 0) {
            System.err.println("popping " + activeIntervals.get(0).name);

            final Interval db = activeIntervals.get(0);
            for (IntervalCounter counter : outgoingIntervals) {
                if (counter.itv.overlaps(db))
                    counter.counter -= 1;
            }

            dbToQueries.remove(db);
            activeIntervals.remove(0);
            popCount--;
        }

        // Write out all queries that are marked as done
        while (!outgoingIntervals.isEmpty() && outgoingIntervals.get(0).counter == 0) {
            System.err.println("Writing out query " + outgoingIntervals.get(0).itv.name);
            outgoingIntervals.remove(0);
        }
    }

    private static void assignToIntervals(Interval q) {
        // Activate new DB intervals
        int popCount = 0;
        for (Interval db : inactiveIntervals) {
            if (q == null || q.end > db.begin) { // could overlap
                activeIntervals.add(db);
                dbToQueries.put(db, new ArrayList<>());
                if (q != null) {
                    outgoingIntervals.add(new IntervalCounter(q));
                    itvToCounter.put(q, outgoingIntervals.get(outgoingIntervals.size() - 1));
                }
                popCount++;
            } else {
                break; // cannot pull in more
            }
        }
        // Activate intervals
        while (popCount > 0) {
            inactiveIntervals.remove(0);
            popCount--;
        }
        // Assign to active DB intervals
        if (q == null)
            return;
        for (Interval db : activeIntervals) {
            if (q.overlaps(db)) {
                dbToQueries.get(db).add(q);
                itvToCounter.get(q).counter += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        ArrayList<Interval> db = new ArrayList<>();
        db.add(new Interval("db1", 1, 100));
        db.add(new Interval("db2", 95, 190));
        db.add(new Interval("db3", 200, 300));

        ArrayList<Interval> qry = new ArrayList<>();
        qry.add(new Interval("q1", 1, 20));
        qry.add(new Interval("q2", 99, 100));
        qry.add(new Interval("q3", 250, 251));

        // Guarantee: db and qry will always be sorted by begin

        process(db, qry);
    }
}
```

The output when running the program above is as follows

```
Processing in DB db1
  q1
  q2
Processing in DB db2
  q2
popping db1
popping db2
Writing out query q1
Writing out query q2
Processing in DB db3
  q3
popping db3
Writing out query q3
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks similar to a stream outer join problem answered in "[How to perform an outer join on two or more Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532067/how-to-perform-an-outer-join-on-two-or-more-streams/39337679#39337679)".  The join implementation employs two blocking queues. Separate threads fill each queue and put an end-of-stream marker in the queue when they run out of data.  A [Spliterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) implementation based on [AbstractSpliterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) consumes values in each queue as needed.

Your case requires a different tryAdvance implementation. A suggested backend stream implementation follows. See the question above for the blocking queue filling parts. Parallelizing the stream is complicated because of the overlapping nature of DB entries and queries. Even so, the proposed implementation supports limited parallelization (see the implementation of [trySplit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) in [AbstractSpliterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)).

I have tested the concepts employed below, but this code is not tested.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

public class QueryProcessor {
    private static class SpliteratorImpl extends AbstractSpliterator<Pair<DbEntry, Query>> {
        private final Query queryEos;
        private final DbEntry dbEntryEos;
        private final BlockingQueue<DbEntry> dbQueue;
        private final BlockingQueue<Query> queryQueue;
        private final Deque<Query> activeQueries = new ArrayDeque<>();
        private final Deque<Pair<DbEntry, Query>> working = new ArrayDeque<>();
        private boolean queriesExhausted = false;

        public SpliteratorImpl(long est, int additionalCharacteristics, BlockingQueue<DbEntry> dbQueue, BlockingQueue<Query> queryQueue, DbEntry dbEntryEos, Query queryEos) {
            super(est, additionalCharacteristics);
            this.dbQueue = dbQueue;
            this.queryQueue = queryQueue;
            this.queryEos = queryEos;
            this.dbEntryEos = dbEntryEos;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Pair<DbEntry, Query>> action) {
            try {
                DbEntry entry = null;
                // tryAdvance produces DbEntry-Query pairs. It begins by
                // draining a working queue of DbEntry-Query pairs, one pair
                // for each tryAdvance call. If the working queue is empty,
                // tryAdvance takes an entry from the entryQueue. For each
                // of these entries, tryAdvance extends its active query queue
                // with queries potentially overlapping the entry and purges
                // queries at the front of the queue that do not overlap the
                // entry. Next, tryAdvance pairs the current entry with each
                // active query that it overlaps.
                //
                // If there are no more DB entries or no active queries, the
                // loop terminates and returns false, signaling that the stream
                // as reached its end.

                for (;;) {
                    // If the working queue is not empty, consume the first pair
                    // in the queue and return true. If it is empty move on to
                    // the next step.
                    if (!working.isEmpty()) {
                        Pair<DbEntry, Query> p = working.pop();
                        action.accept(p);
                        return true;
                    }

                    // Take the next entry form the DB entry queue.
                    entry = dbQueue.take();
                    if (entry == dbEntryEos) {
                        // Encountered end-of-stream in DB entries -- we're
                        // done.
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Extend the the active query queue with any queries that
                    // potentially overlap the current DB entry. If the end of
                    // the last query proceeds the end of the DB entry by more
                    // than one unit, it is possible that the next query will
                    // overlap with this last uncovered bit of the entry.
                    while (!queriesExhausted
                        && (activeQueries.peekLast() == null || activeQueries.peekLast().end() + 1 < entry.end())) {
                        Query q = queryQueue.take();
                        if (q == queryEos) {
                            queriesExhausted = true;
                        } else if (q.end() > entry.begin()) {
                            // if the end of this q follows the beginning of the
                            // entry, keep the query; otherwise, discard it (it
                            // won't overlap any of the following entries
                            // either).
                            activeQueries.add(q);
                        } else {
                            // Discard queries whose end proceed the beginning
                            // of the entry interval.
                        }
                    }

                    // Pop any queries in the working queue that proceed the
                    // current entry (there was overlap between them and prior
                    // entries).
                    for (;;) {
                        if (activeQueries.peekFirst() != null && activeQueries.peekFirst().end() <= entry.begin()) {
                            activeQueries.pop();
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // If the active query queue is empty, there is nothing left
                    // that I can do.
                    if (!activeQueries.isEmpty()) {
                        // Pair each query in the active query queue with the
                        // current entry if it overlaps the current entry.
                        for (Query q : activeQueries) {
                            if (isOverlapping(entry, q)) {
                                working.add(Pair.of(entry, q));
                            }
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    // The active query queue is empty; so, return false to
                    // signal the end of the stream.
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static boolean isOverlapping(DbEntry entry, Query q) {
            return (q.begin() <= entry.begin() && entry.begin() < q.end())
                || q.begin() <= entry.end() && entry.end() < q.end();
        }
    }

    private QueryProcessor() {
    }

    public static Stream<Pair<DbEntry, Query>> stream(long est, int additionalCharacteristics,
            BlockingQueue<DbEntry> dbQueue, BlockingQueue<Query> queryQueue, DbEntry dbEntryEos, Query queryEos) {
        Spliterator<Pair<DbEntry, Query>> spliterator =
            new SpliteratorImpl(est, additionalCharacteristics, dbQueue, queryQueue, dbEntryEos, queryEos);

        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
    }
}
```